# How can I simulate keystrokes in Bash, without any packages?

Tags: linux

I want to simulate keystrokes in my bash script ("Ctrl+B + O" for example) but I do not know how I can do it.

Also, I cannot install any packages for doing this. I want to use this script on Termux.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Contr`+`A` relates to the ASCII value of `1`, `Contr`+`B` to `2` etc.

If you want to send a control combination, use `echo $'\c<key>'`.

For example, you can use `echo $'\cb'` instead of `Contr`+`B`+`O`.

```
$ echo $'\ca'|bash
bash: line 1: $'\001': command not found
$ cat|bash
^B
bash: line 1: $'\002': command not found
```

In the second command, I emulated `Contr`+`B` using the keys and pressed enter.